# Core Data Predicates with Subclassed NSManagedObjects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, nspredicate

I have an AUDIO class.  This audio has a SOUND_A subclass and a SOUND_B subclass.  This is all done correctly and is working fine.

I have another model, lets call it PLAYLIST_JOIN, and this can contain (in the real world) SOUND_A's and SOUND_B's, so we give it a relationship of AUDIO and PLAYLIST.

This all works in the app.

The problem I am having now is querying the PLAYLIST_JOIN table with an NSPredicate.  What I want to do is find an exact PLAYLIST_JOIN item by giving it 2 keys in the predicate

```
sound_a._sound_a_id = %@ && playlist.playlist_id = %@
```

and

```
sound_b.sound_b_id = %@ && playlist.playlist_id = %@
```

The main problem is that because the table does not store `sound_a` and `sound_b`, but stored `audio`, I cannot use this syntax.  I do not have the option of reorganizing the sound_a and sound_b to use the same _id attribute name, so how do I do this?

Can I pass a method to the predicate? something like this:

`[audio getID] = %@ && playlist_id = %@`

Comment: Why don't you have the option of using the same _id attribute? The entity AUDIO should have the _id attribute, which SOUND_A and SOUND_B should both inherit.

Comment: I don't want to get into too many details, but the id's reference remote tables that are not the same.  I could wrap it in an if statement around the predicate, but it would make my life a WHOLE lot easier if there is a way to do it like the last code blob in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets a little complicated but you need to add a third condition to the predicate:

```
(entity.name = sound_a && _sound_a_id = %@ && playlist.playlist_id = %@) && (entity.name = sound_b && sound_b_id = %@ && playlist.playlist_id = %@)
```

This is assuming you are querying against the audio abstract and telling it to return subclasses.  Because the condition is checked left to right, if the first condition fails it will move on and not throw errors because _sound_a_id does not exist.

The first condition is referencing the `NSEntityDescription` that is a part of the `NSManagedObject` and its `name` attribute is just a string.

Comment: Thanks Marcus.  I looked in your book for the answer first btw :)  Shouldn't it be an || in the middle of the 2?

Comment: Up to you, I don't know your exact logic :)  You had a && in your original question.